# How to properly map piped values to ForEach-Object in remote connection in PowerShell

Tags: powershell

I have next code:

```bsh
$Dom = Get-ADDomain 
$DomIs = $dom.DNsRoot
$GetComp = Get-ADComputer -Filter 'enabled -eq "true"'

$CertGridComp = ($Computer | ForEach-Object {
        Invoke-Command -Cn $GetComp.Name -ScriptBlock {
        Get-ChildItem -Path Cert:LocalMachine\* -Recurse | 
        Select-Object PSComputerName, NotAfter, Issuer, NotBefore, Subject,PSPath
        }
       )| Out-GridView -Title  "Select Certificates to Delete" -PassThru

$Compdel | ForEach-Object {
    Invoke-Command -Cn $CertGridComp.PSComputerName {Remove-Item -path $Using:CertGridComp.PSPath -whatif}
 }
```

I need to pass mapped value selection from OGV to perform proper deletion. With above code after selection I have issue that every

```bsh
CertGridComp.PSPath
```

value is passed to each selection thus multiplying output but also giving error since not every cert path exists on selected computer.
How can I format ForEach-Object to invoke command for selected computer to use its own cert path only and not other path(s) from selection as well.

Thanks.

Comment: Where does `$Computer` come from? Do you really need to pass it to the current users computer as a gridview, or do you know what you want to delete? The reason I ask is because you're connecting to the computer twice, when I think you could handle something like this during the life of one session.

Comment: Thanks Andrew for feedback. With $Computer I was able to produce  output to OGV that I needed. As Doug noticed that was probably not necessary.  Not every time will be known what to be deleted but as well it will serve as tool to investigate certificates from one place since OGV has nice "Add criteria" option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure where `$Compdel` came from. That said, I will make a few assumptions.

1. You may end up with more than one cert per machine
2. You probably don't want to make more than one Invoke-Command call per machine
3. `$CertGridComp` already contains all the information you need.

Based on these, I would change your `Invoke-Command` to this.

```
$CertGridComp | Group-Object -Property pscomputername | foreach {
    Invoke-Command -cn $_.name -ScriptBlock {$using:_.group.pspath | foreach {Remove-Item -path $_ -WhatIf}}
}
```

First, we group each entry by the pscomputername. Then we call one invoke-command call per name of the group, which is the PC name. Next we still use `$using` but against the automatic variable `$_` which makes it look a little odd. We provide each path for each certificate to delete (even if it's just one.) This should accomplish what you're wanting to.

Edit: I also see what Andrew is referring to about `$Computer` - oddly enough the command works but that part is unnecessary. This is essentially what is actually running.

```
$CertGridComp = Invoke-Command -Cn $GetComp.Name -ScriptBlock {
                    Get-ChildItem -Path Cert:LocalMachine\* -Recurse
                } | Select-Object PSComputerName, NotAfter, Issuer, NotBefore, Subject,PSPath |
                        Out-GridView -Title  "Select Certificates to Delete" -PassThru
```

Reformatted, the entire script could look like this

```
$DomIs = (Get-ADDomain).DNsRoot
$GetComp = Get-ADComputer -Filter "enabled -eq 'true'"

Invoke-Command -Cn $GetComp.Name -ScriptBlock {
    Get-ChildItem -Path Cert:LocalMachine\* -Recurse
} | Select-Object PSComputerName, NotAfter, Issuer, NotBefore, Subject,PSPath |
        Out-GridView -Title  "Select Certificates to Delete" -PassThru -OutVariable CertGridComp

$CertGridComp | Group-Object -Property pscomputername | foreach {
    Invoke-Command -cn $_.name -ScriptBlock {$using:_.group.pspath | foreach {Remove-Item -path $_ -WhatIf}}
}
```